# How to access sonar property file while analyzing the projects

Tags: sonarqube

How to access sonar property file while analyzing the projects.I need base folder which we have to mention in sonar-project property file.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement constructor of Sensor implementation class like this:

```
public class CodeSensor implements Sensor {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final FileSystem filesystem;
    private final Settings settings;
    private final ResourcePerspectives perspectives;

    public CodeSensor(Settings settings, FileSystem filesystem, ResourcePerspectives perspectives) {
            this.filesystem = filesystem;
            this.settings = settings;
            this.perspectives = perspectives;

            try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = 
                Files.newDirectoryStream(filesystem.baseDir().toPath().toAbsolutePath(),
                            settings.getString("sonar.sources"))) {
                    for (Path entry : stream) {
                            DirectoryStream<Path> file = 
                                Files.newDirectoryStream(entry, "*.q");

                            for (Path path : file) {
                                    path.toFile().delete();
                            }
                    }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                    log.error("Can't clean src dir", e1);
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the path to Your settings param: settings.getString("sonar.sources")

here is the path to Your base folder: filesystem.baseDir().toPath().toAbsolutePath()